# Customers who ordered 'X' and did not ordered 'Y' (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

Suppose that there is a database with this tables:

**Orders**

```
OrderId  -  CustomerId
----------------------
100      -  1
101      -  2
102      -  1
```

**Order_Details**

```
DetailId  -  OrderId -  ProductId
---------------------------------
1         -  100     -  prod1
2         -  100     -  prod2
3         -  101     -  prod1
4         -  102     -  prod3
```

I need to get a list of CustomerIds who bought *product '1'* but never bought *product '2'*.

With the sample data provided, I should get CustomerId 2.

I wrote this SQL sentence, but the real database is really big and it runs very slow...
Is there a way of improve my sentence?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(o.CustomerId) 
FROM orders o 
JOIN order_details od ON od.orderId = o.orderId
WHERE od.productId = 'prod1'
AND o.customerId NOT IN
  (SELECT DISTINCT(o.CustomerId) FROM order_details od2 WHERE
  od2.productId = 'prod2');
```

Thanks!

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT(o.CustomerId) FROM order_details od2 WHERE
  od2.productId = 'prod2'` but `CustomerId` is not inside table `order_details`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `IN` operator is not recommended for a large values list.
Instead, you can either use [`EXISTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) or add more joins to your query.

Using Exists:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(o.CustomerId) 
FROM orders o 
JOIN order_details od ON od.orderId = o.orderId
WHERE od.productId = 'prod1'
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM orders o2 
    JOIN order_details od2 ON od2.orderId = o2.orderId
    WHERE o2.customerId = o.customerId 
    AND od2.productId = 'prod2'
);
```

Using Joins:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(o.CustomerId) 
FROM orders o 
INNER JOIN order_details od ON od.orderId = o.orderId
LEFT JOIN  order_details od2 ON od2.orderId = o.orderId AND od2.productId = 'prod1'
WHERE od.productId = 'prod1'
AND od2.DetailId IS NULL -- Assuming that the detailId column does not allow null values.
```

**Note:** Code was written directly here and not tested, I might have made some mistakes. To get better answers, I suggest always including DDL + DML for sample data in your query, so that people will be able to check the answers before posting them.

Answer (score 2):

You may convert the `sub-query` to `exists` mechanism 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.CustomerId
FROM orders o 
JOIN order_details od ON od.orderId = o.orderId
WHERE od.productId = 'prod1'
and not exists(
 select 1 from order_details od2 
 WHERE o.customerId = od2.customerId
 and od2.productId = 'prod2'
)
```

Now in addition you will need to have indexing for this.

Assuming `orderId` is a primary key on `orders` and its already indexed on `order_details` you need

```
alter table order_details add index productId_idx(productId);
```

If `orderId` is not indexed on `order_details` add the following

```
alter table order_details add index orderId_idx(orderId);
```

Comment: orders table does not contain productId, it belongs on the order_details table. wouldn't it be better to add the index on both orderId and productId? `alter table order_details add index orderId_idx(orderId, productId);`

Answer (score 2):

Try use **MINUS**

```
SELECT DISTINCT(o.CustomerId) 
FROM orders o 
JOIN order_details od ON od.orderId = o.orderId
WHERE od.productId = 'prod1'

MINUS

SELECT DISTINCT(o2.CustomerId) 
FROM orders o2 
JOIN order_details od2 ON od2.orderId = o2.orderId
WHERE o2.customerId = o.customerId 
AND od2.productId = 'prod2'
```